# Create a Dicom image

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, dicom, im4java

I am currently working with a DICOM project in java. I am calculating the dicom values such as depth, off-axis ratio, width and height. I want to create a sample image with the calculated width and height. I should be a gray scale image, with varying densities of gray color in appropriate area. I have created a sample image with imagemagick, using concentric circles. Bit am not getting the exact image. It does not look like an actual dicom image. The variation of gray color does not have a linear behavior. Sample image is attached. Please suggest any other method to create dicom image. The density values are available in a list. depending upon the distance from the center, the gray color also changes according to the density value provided. [image]

Comment: might i ask you 'how' you draw that image? that could provide much help on solving that issue - it doesn't look so problematic for me but i can't help yet...  i (we) need more information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixel Data or image in DICOM data set is always rectangular and image is described using Rows (0028, 0010) and Columns (0028, 0011) attributes. So the best way to implement this is to draw your circular image on a rectangular background. Fill the background with a color that is not present in your image. Use the Pixel Padding Value (0028,0120) to specify the color used to pad grayscale images (those with a Photometric Interpretation of MONOCHROME1 or MONOCHROME2) to rectangular format.

If you do not have any color to spare (with-in the bit stored), you can add Overlay Plane or Display Shutter to the data set to mask the area that is not part of image.